# Click Event is triggered around the actual button

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic App. I have a ion-list with click events on the ion-item in it. The click event will be triggered also when i click the ion-list item

**ion-item** trigger onclick only here

[image: ion-item]

**ion-list** red mark shows where i can trigger the event

[image: ion-list]

```html
     <div>
        <ion-list *ngFor="let y of x">
            <p>Date</p>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let z of y" (click)="click(y.id)">
                {{event.title}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
```

The small gap between the items is clickable... Why and how can i channge it?

**SOLUTION**

Add event.stopPropagation() to the click event.

```
click(id :string){
  event.stopPropagation();
  //more code
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to place the click event on the paragraph?  Please clarify.

Comment: click event only on the blue ion-item not on the white space around it

Comment: Wrap your text with a span, or a div, and put the `(click)` on it: `<div (click)="click(event.id)">{{event.title}}</div>`

Comment: click event on div has same behavior has bevore :/

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz showing the problem? What is `event`?

Comment: I did not know stackblitz before. I will use it for my next question. Now I already have a solution. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should stop `event bubbling` to stop click on parent element: you should use `event.stopPropagation()` for this

Comment: This works for me. Thank you! I add a solution with code to my question